# How can I have HTML elements as labels for radio buttons?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to have HTML-formatted choices on the choices of a radioButton element.

I was able to make an HTML-formatted label for a sliderInput as such:

```
sliderInput("bins",
HTML("Number of <u>bins</u>&alpha;<sub>1</sub>:"),
min = 1,
max = 50,
value = 30)
```

I was hoping that something like this following code block would work for radioButton

```
radioButtons("dist", "Distribution type:",
c(HTML("Normal &mu;<sub>1</sub>") = "norm",
"Uniform" = "unif",
"Log-normal" = "lnorm",
"Exponential" = "exp"))
```

However, the above code block throws an error.  I looked a bit more into how radioButtons executes (https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/blob/8546918cbbc240e23b622d3c5c8181090deb7d62/R/input-utils.R).  Eventually, a method called "generateOptions" is called to produce the text labels for the radio buttons.

```
inputTag <- tags$input(
type = type, name = inputId, value = value
)
```

If I could replace

```
value = value
```

with

```
value = HTML(value)
```

I think that might be able to solve my problem.  Any ideas for how to proceed?

Comment: I've filled [an issue](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1437#issue-185093306) about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi eventually you can build your radiobuttons by hand... Like this :

```
## ui.R
ui <- fluidPage(
  # classic radiobuttons
  radioButtons(inputId = "dist2", label = "Distribution type:",
               choices = list("Normal &mu;<sub>1</sub" = "rnorm", "Uniform" = "runif")),
  br(),
  # custom radiobuttoms
  tags$div(
    id="dist", class="form-group shiny-input-radiogroup shiny-input-container",
    tags$label(class="control-label", `for`="dist", "Distribution type:"),
    tags$div(class="shiny-options-group",
             tags$div(class="radio",
                      tags$label(
                        tags$input(type="radio", name="dist", value="rnorm", checked="checked",
                                   tags$span(HTML("Normal &mu;<sub>1</sub")))
                      )
             ),
             tags$div(class="radio",
                      tags$label(
                        tags$input(type="radio", name="dist", value="runif",
                                   tags$span(HTML("Uniform")))
                      )
             )
    )
  ),
  verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "test")
)
## server.R
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$test <- renderPrint({
    print("id = dist2")
    print(input$dist2)
    print("")
    print("id = dist")
    print(input$dist)
  })
}
# launch app
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Wow!  Thank you.  This is much more elegant than what I was anticipating.